# What is the maximum storage limit for db that is specific to a single app?

Tags: android

I need to know important limits in sqlite in the android. so my question is this:

What is the maximum storage limit for db that is specific to a single app?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is no maximum storage. As long as you store the database in the SDcard, I think it should grow as much as the SDcard allows. This is the idea of databases right ? Probably you can specify how big you allow the database to be, but there shouldn't be a maximum storage.

Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html